# Remote Integration - UDP/TCP protocols

Tags: thingsboard

I'm about to add some devices to my Thinsgboard instance, although I'm not sure if they can be easily integrated with.

Someone can tell if with a UDP or TCP remote integration I can receive messages from a device using IEC 60870–5‑104 and HAC-NBh? I need confirmation for both protocols.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I can't tell you anything specific about protocols that you mentioned, but UDP integration with my Dragino CPN-01 device did work without a problem. For the mentioned protocols you may need to write some decoder software.